# Can Animate Undead be used on the same corpse multiple times?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, undead, kobold-press

The spell [Animate Undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/kobold-press-open-design/animate-dead/) (not [Animate Dead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/)), animates a corpse for a number of rounds equal to your level. After this duration, the undead presumably becomes a corpse again.

The spell has the following to say:

> a soul is present in any corporeal remains for which the creature has not been resurrected or previously animated as an undead. a soul can also be obtained from trap the soul, magic jar, or similar magic.

but the spell doesn't outright state that a soul is required, at least on the d20PFSRD.  As written, I am unsure if a corpse that had already been used for Animate Undead is a valid target for a further casting of Animate Undead. Can I cast Animate Undead on the same corpse again?

I have already looked at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/can-the-spell-create-undead-be-used-on-the-remains-of-a-skeleton-that-was-itself), but it is referring to a different spell and situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A soul is required for some undead, but not all of them. Starting with *Animate Undead III*, in the table, the Shadow appears to be the first Undead which requires a soul.

Unless you're dealing with one of the small handful of undead which require souls, which you can't re-animate due to the line

> a soul is present in any corporeal remains for which the creature has not been resurrected or previously animated as an undead.

I would say the important line is

> Remains must be mostly intact.

So, as long as the remains are "mostly intact" after each casting, it would appear you can keep re-animating them.